# How to download music or movie while playing music or movie from a url?

Tags: objective-c

I want to download music or movie while playing music or movie from a url like this:

```
[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.7:8080/Music/music.mp3"] error:nil];
```

so I think I should cut up little data

```
NSMutableData *totalData;
[totalData appendData:firstData];[totalData appendData:secondData];
[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:totalData error:nil];
```

but I don't know how to get totalData.length

I use NSURLSessionDownloadTask, I don't want to use NSURLConnection, because
 `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

But Use `[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]` onlyfinishDownloading return data

or maybe I can use `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location`

My idea may be wrong,I think get location can use to playing when play finished I can move caches or delete

`[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location error:nil];
 but location onlyfinishDownloading return location`

I know  how to download data in tmp file, though do anyone know how to get location and the response when begin download ?

**Update**:My problem like this [iOS Objective-C/Swift read file while downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084185/ios-objective-c-swift-read-file-while-downloading)

I'm trying to play an audio file while it's downloading, is that possible in iOS?
I know I can get the location of the file "after" it's downloaded through:
But I need to read/play it while it's still downloading.

Comment: By all means, try to be more specific, it's already hard as it is to understand what you want.

Comment: No I don't believe you can get the location of the temporary file before it's complete.  Why do you need it?

Comment: My idea may be wrong,I think get location can use to playing when play finished I can move caches or delete